# Hex2ascii dictionary module for non printable chars

Tags: python, module, hex, non-printable

I want to convert hexadecimal chars like:

```
\x12h+.\xC9V\xB8\xFC\x95\x0D\x11
```

to

```
(Device Control 2)h+.(+)V(+)(n)(ò)(Carriage Return)(Device Control 1)
```

Is there a module available in python or something similar that can easily do this without having to create a hex2text dictionary?

[Non printable char reference @ Istanbul Technical University](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html)

Comment: In what charset do those bytes >0x80 translate to those characters?

Comment: I'm unsure of the charset. I added a reference that I found online and it seems that other online sources seem to have the same chars. I checked `\x40` to be @ as a sanity check.

Comment: 0x40 is `@` in a very large number of charsets. The important question is how you got from 0x95 to `ò`.

Comment: Good point, that character is different from the first reference I pointed to. I used [juniper's reference](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html) and it was in Table 2. This question arose from seeing hexadecimal chars in cross site scripting attacks in access logs. I want to find out what each of the hex chars mean without having to google each one.